# Troubleshooting with wiki pages

Tags: migration, wiki-pages, troubleshooting

I recently upgraded SP2010 Farm to SP2013.

After Database Attach upgrade I went on and did site collection upgrade.
All pages work fine with the exception of the wiki pages which seem to remained in 2010 v14 (instead of 2013 v15)

I get a javascript error and can't modify anything.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'ListId' of null

It's about :

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_WikiField_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte').ListId = 'e2248123-245b-3972-8111-c3db7ee5g33a';
```

Any idea ?

Comment: my "hello" doesn't appear :\

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this same issue after we upgraded from 2010 to 2013. There's an asp tag called UpdatePanel that doesn't seem to work in 2013 and causes this issue. To fix this, we had to go in to each wiki page in Designer, edit them in advanced mode, and remove the following:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel
       id="updatePanel"
       runat="server"
       UpdateMode="Conditional"
       ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
```

Then scroll to the bottom and remove the closing UpdatePanel tag. After that, the wiki pages should once again be editable. I know this response is a little late, but I hope it helps.